# How to return a custom message with @UniqueConstraint and @Column(unique = true)

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa, exception

I would be capable to return a custom message when a user send a data that already existis in database.

There is my class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="unity")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Unity {

    \\...

    @CNPJ(message = "O CNPJ é inválido")
    @NotNull(message = "Preencha o campo CNPJ")
    @Column(name="cnpj", unique = true )
    private String cnpj;
    
    \\...
```

I would like to sent a constraint error as the `@NotNull` anottation does, so i can grab it in the  `validator` within the controller.

```
    @POST
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Response create(UnityDTO unityDTO){
        
        Set<ConstraintViolation<UnityDTO>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(unityDTO);
    
            if (constraintViolations.isEmpty()) {
                UnityDTO unityDTOPersisted = unityMapper.unityToUnityDTO(unityService.save(unityDTO));
                return Response
                        .fromResponse(
                                createdResponse(unityDTOPersisted.getId(), UnityEndpoint.class)
                        ).entity(unityDTOPersisted).build();
            } else {
                Set<String> errors = constraintViolations.stream().map(ConstraintViolation::getMessage).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(errors).build();
            }


            }
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Are you using Spring/Spring Boot?

Comment: A solution is DB specific - you need to look at the error that is thrown on the constraint error, parse it for your particular constraint as they usually return the name of the constraint, and return your message instead. JPA layers wrap DB exceptions in persistence exceptions, and I believe Hibernate will as well so it will take some digging to get at the underlying cause. Catching that exception depends on the app. JPA providers may allow hooks to get into it, but it will still be wrapped in JPA exceptions, so may not help, so you might need it at the DAO layer of your app code